# Why does this code generate incorrect data?

Tags: java, android, timestamp

I have this code in my project

```
    Calendar subval = Calendar.getInstance();
    final int WOY= subval.WEEK_OF_YEAR;
```

and when I check it for value of WOY it outputs 3 now it is currently Feb 25 2013 and I know the week number is not three. I am storing this value to help set automatic refresh times so I am able to force a refresh to make sure the device has the most current data. In between refresh periods some crucial data is stored locally. Now I need a reliable fixed time slot and I chose once a week basically if the WEEK OF YEAR is not the same as the stored value for WEEK OF YEAR set data to be refreshed at next opportunity and then store current WEEK OF YEAR on device. I started coding this within 1 week so I have not transitioned to the new week so I am not sure if it working correctly but the value of three scares me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WEEK_OF_YEAR is a flag used to the get() method. It's value never changes.
You use it like this:

```
Calendar subval = Calendar.getInstance();
final int WOY= subval.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

Comment: Thank you it works now eclipse fooled me on this one it said I could use the format I used but it was actually incorrect. Any idea what that 3 was representing

Comment: 3 is just a flag: it is so that Calendar.get(int flag) can say { if (flag == 3) { return some_method_to_calculate_the_week(); }

Answer (score 2):

[Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#WEEK_OF_YEAR) is a constant to be used to specify which field to return from your `Calendar` instance. Instead of assigning the value to the fixed value, you need to call `Calendar#get`:

```
int WOY = subval.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get it like this

```
 Calendar subval = Calendar.getInstance();
   int year=subval.get(Calender.Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

Answer (score 1):

Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR is a static constant.

You need to call `calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)`

Answer (score 0):

Subclasses define WEEK_OF_YEAR for days before the first week of year according to the java oracle documentation

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

see: week_of_year